# Difficulty halting C++ threads using conditional variables and atomic bools

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm encountering issues in stopping a C++ thread within my application. The core parts of the thread functions involve the usage of mutexes and conditional variables:

```cpp
class Acqer {
    std::atomic_bool running_;
    std::atomic_bool acquiring_;
    std::mutex dataMutex;
    std::condition_variable acqCV;
    std::condition_variable dataCV;

    std::jthread acqThread;
    std::jthread procThread;
    
public:
    void AcquireData();
    void ProcessData();
    void StartThreads();
    void StopThreads();
};

void Acqer::AcquireData() {
    while (running_)
    {
        // ...

        // Lock the mutex
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(dataMutex);
        // Use a condition variable to start the acquisition
        acqCV.wait(lock, [this]() -> bool
                   { return acquiring_; });

        // ...

        // Unlock the mutex
        lock.unlock();

        // Notify ProcessData thread
        dataCV.notify_one();

        // ...
    }
}

void Acqer::ProcessData() {
    while (running_)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(dataMutex);
        dataCV.wait(lock);

        // ...

        // Unlock the mutex
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

void Acqer::StartThreads()
{
    running_ = true;
    cout << "Starting acquisition and processing threads..." << endl;
    acqThread_ = jthread(&Acqer::AcquireData, this);
    procThread_ = jthread(&Acqer::ProcessData, this);
    cout << "Threads started." << endl;
}

void Acqer::StopThreads()
{
    running_ = false;
    acqCV.notify_all();
    dataCV.notify_all();
}
```

Despite utilizing atomic bools *running_* and *acquiring_* along with mutexes and conditional variables, the thread *AcquireData* persists even after invoking the *StopThreads* function.
I've tried to debug the code and I've noticed that I can stop both threads only when the acquisition hasn't started yet (*acqCV* is still waiting).

It also seems that the AcquireData thread doesn't reach the acqCV.wait(...) line when I set running_ to false, but still is not joinable.

Are there potential issues or considerations that might prevent these threads from halting even after signaling termination?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the predicate form of `wait`. This means that even if a thread should be woken up then it'll immediately wait again if the predicate returns false.

When you stop your threads you wake up the `AcquireData` thread but it'll immediately `wait` again as `acquiring_` is (presumably?) false. You need to also check `_running` in your predicate. Do this instead:

```
acqCV.wait(lock, [this]() -> bool
                   { return acquiring_ || !running_; });
if (!_running) break;
```

Comment: The first part is actually the behaviour I want the threads to have: run the while loop while running_ and acquiring_ are true, while being able to "pause" them by setting acquiring_ to false. The AcquireData seems to hang (while not being joinable) before even getting to the acqCV.wait line.

Comment: Thats fine. This will still do that. With my change it'll additionally stop waiting when running is set to false and terminate the loop. Which is presumably what you want. Else your question makes no sense?

Comment: I've added those lines but it still doesn't work. It seems that the AcquireData thread doesn't reach the acqCV.wait(...) line when I set running_ to false, but still seems not joinable.

Comment: In which case you'll need to debug. Get into the situation where you think you'll be able to join, and using a debugger examine the call stacks of those threads to see exactly where they are now blocked.

Comment: The only other thing I can see which could be an issue, you could be in the situation where you are trying to join the threads in the via the destructor of `Acqer`. This would be bad.

Comment: The reason being if you are joining using `jthreads` implicit join-on-destruction for example `_ acqThread_` then this means that your CVs, atomics and mutexes _have already been destroyed whilst in use_. You could see if that is your issue by moving `std::jthread acqThread; std::jthread procThread;` to the _top_ of your class - although this isn't a real fix it'd tell you why this is happening.

Comment: @caccolona Provide a **minimal reproducible sample** please. It looks like there's something in other parts of the code.